# How to use multiple IR signals for doing the same thing?

Tags: c++, arduino, logical-operators

I want to use different signals from different IR remotes to control a wheeled robot.

The robot is the Smart robot car kit v1.0 from Elegoo.
I used the `infrared_remote_control_car.ino` file from the disc with it.
I just added the `#define JVC` and the operators at the end.

The code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>
int receiverpin = 12;
int in1=9;
int in2=8;
int in3=7;
int in4=6;
int ENA=10;
int ENB=5;
int ABS=130;
unsigned long RED;

#define A 16736925
#define B 16754775
#define X 16712445
#define C 16720605
#define D 16761405

#define JVCfront 49816
#define JVCback 49688
#define JVCright 49704
#define JVCleft 49832
#define JVCmenu 49900
#define JVC3ok 49724
#define JVCstop 49856


IRrecv irrecv(receiverpin);
decode_results results;

void _mForward()
{  
  digitalWrite(ENA,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4,HIGH);
  Serial.println("go forward!");
}
void _mBack()
{
  digitalWrite(ENA,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4,LOW);
  Serial.println("go back!");
}
void _mleft()
{
  analogWrite(ENA,ABS);
  analogWrite(ENB,ABS);
  digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4,LOW);
  Serial.println("go left!");
}
void _mright()
{
  analogWrite(ENA,ABS);
  analogWrite(ENB,ABS);
  digitalWrite(in1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4,HIGH);
  Serial.println("go right!");
}
void _mStop()
{
  digitalWrite(ENA,LOW);
  digitalWrite(ENB,LOW);
  Serial.println("STOP!");  
}
void setup() {
  pinMode(in1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENA,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENB,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(receiverpin,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  _mStop();
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
  {
    RED=results.value;
    Serial.println(RED);
    irrecv.resume();
    delay(150);
    if(RED==(A || JVCfront))
    {  
       _mForward();
    }
    else if(RED==(B or JVCback))
    {
      _mBack();
    }
    else if(RED==(C or JVCleft))
    {
      _mleft();
    }
    else if(RED==(D or JVCright))
    {
      _mright();
    }
    else if(RED==(X or JVCstop or JVCmenu or JVC3ok))
    { 
      _mStop();
    }
  }
}
```

I tried different ways I saw on the internet for the OR operator as you can see.
Actually, the robot is always going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the `Serial.println(RED)` always print out the expected value?
Your `if-else`block itself does not seem to be problematic at first glance. It doesn't matter if you use `||` or `or`. They are equivalent.
The problem is the way you are checking the value:

Therefore that you have parenthesis around your OR statement, you create a bool-value. `if(RED==(A || JVCfront)` translates to:

- is `A` set or is `JVCfront` set; meaning, are they != 0 (yes they both are, so this expression is `true`
- is `RED == true` (no it is not, because `true` represents `1` in integer)
- so the code in that block is not being executed

If you want to solve it with an if-else, you need to:

```
if(RED == A or RED == JVCfront)
{
    _mForward();
}
```

Anyway, I would suggest a switch-case statement:

```
switch(RED):
{
    case A:
    {
        //intentional fallthrough
    }
    case JVCfront:
    {
        _mForward();
        break;
    }
    case B:
    {
        //intentional fallthrough
    }
    case JVCback:
    {
        _mBack();
        break;
    }
    case C: 
    {
        //intentional fallthrough
    }
    case JVCleft:
    {
        _mleft();
        break;
    }
    case D:
    {
        //intentional fallthrough
    }
    case JVCright:
    {
        _mright();
        break;
    }
    case X:
    {
        //intentional fallthrough
    }
    case JVCstop:
    {
        //intentional fallthrough
    }
    case JVCmenu:
    {
        //intentional fallthrough
    }
    case JVC3ok:
    {
        _mStop();
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        _mStop();
    }
}
```

I personally find this kind of code much easier to read, and more understandable.
Please note: If you dont put a `break` into a case, it automatically executes the next `case` as well. This is why I wrote `//intentional fallthrough` in this part of the code. P.e. when `case A` is executed, nothing happens. It just falls through into `case JVCFront` and executes everything there.

Comment: I didn’t check if the serial monitor is printing the correct button

Comment: I’ll try this ans I will get back to you as soon as I can

Comment: Now the different buttons are working well but the robot allways stop after half a second. Any ways to make the robot moving continuously?

Comment: then remove the `_m_stop()` from the `default` block. This block is being called everytime, if none of the previous statements can be applied.